# Proper way to deal with return values when using try/catch

Tags: php, wordpress, try-catch

I am working on a wordpress plugin that deals with an external API. I want to use a try/catch block for the API call but I am not sure if the way I am dealing with the return value is ok.

```
try {
            $response = wp_remote_post($url,$args);

            $communication_location = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $response, 'location' );
            $communication_location_arr = explode('/', $communication_location);

            $communication_id = end($communication_location_arr);
            $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);

        }

        catch (Exception $e){
            throw new Exception('Something went wrong when trying to create the communication');
        }

        return array(0 => $response_code,1 => $communication_id);
```

Should the try block only contain the wp_remote_post call?

Comment: Generally speaking the portion of the code that is able to throw an Exception is only needed in the `try` block. The `catch` block is meant to provide you with a means to handle the Exception. Otherwise It would depend on the order of operations you're wanting to accomplish, which isn't very clear in your question. What you have appears to be fine, since if any part of the `try` block throws an Exception, it would prevent the `return` value from being reached, which is dependant on the variables in the entire `try` block. So I would move the `return` value in the `try` block as well.

Comment: Don't you have to define your exceptions before you do any of this?

Answer (score 0):

The methods of object are attached to the init action hook, and are thrown when the init hook is fired, not when the object is created, and not when they're attached.

```html
class SomeClass {
    public function __construct() {
        // when the init action/event happens, call the wp_some_method
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wp_some_method' ) );
    }
    function wp_some_method( $post_type ){
        throw new \Exception('error'); 
    }
}
try{
    // great, no exceptions where thrown while creating the object
    $o = new SomeClass();    
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

// a small period of time later somewhere in WP Core...

do_action( 'init' ); // a method we attached to the init hook threw an exception, but nothing was there to catch it!
```

These would be more appropriate:

- add a try catch in the class methods ( best )
- Don't throw exceptions in functions attached to hooks/events ( even better )
- throw the exception in a new method that isn't the method you attached so you can add in a try catch ( okay, requires good separation of concerns and abstraction )
- add a global error handler ( hackish, strongly advise against, will take more time than its worth, may catch other exceptions that you never intended to catch )

Otherwise there is no rational, logical, common sense reason why the line of code that says throw new \Exception should be executed inside the try catch block as you have above without you purposefully calling it manually as you did in your test.

Comment: I am not sure I follow -  the code posted is part of a class method, I just didn't copy the whole method.

Comment: The answer was copy-pasted from here, without giving credit to the author. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137112